# php query for mysql text

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, text

i'm having problems while querying for mysql "text" data.

here's my code:

```
$result_odg = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE data = '" . $today . "' AND odg IS NOT NULL");
echo "<h4>ODG:</h4>";

if (mysqli_fetch_array($result_odg)) {
    $i = 1;
    echo "<table id=\"agenda_odg\">";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_odg)) {
        if($i % 2 == 0)
            $cellID = "even";
        else
            $cellID = "odd";
        echo "<tr id=" . $cellID . "><td>" . $row['testo'] . "</td></tr>";
        $i == $i++;
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "No ODG";
}
```

the table have the following fields: id, data_ins, data, testo, odg, agenda, ok.

using any other name than "testo" in `$row['testo']` (example `$row['id']`) will print out the text. is there any special query to do for "TEXT" type fields? maybe because it's too heavy and needs a particular array? can't find anything about this on the manual...

Comment: ids for HTML elements should be unique, use a class for odd or even

Comment: Why do you have `$i==$i++;` alone in your code? The interpreter does the comparison here and returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`, but the result of the expression isn't assigned to a variable.

Comment: Nothing special needed for text type columns. Is the spelling correct? You could print the `$row` array to make sure it is there - `print_r($row);`

Comment: @Sean `print_r($row)` returns nothing. it is spelled correctly as if i copy and paste the query in phpmyadmin i get at least 1 result...

Comment: ok, i have an update: the problem is that ONLY THE FIRST result is not being printed...............
i inserted some new rows and i noticed this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use

```
// no need to fetch the result for check (shorten runtime time)
if ($result_odg) {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_odg)) {
        // use $row['testo'] is possible

        // replace this too
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: @l736k : the difference between **fetch_array** and _fetch_assoc_ is that the first one fetches the result into **an array with numeric index**.
The second one fetches the result into _an associative array_ where you can access the variables by using a string as index.

Comment: ok thanks for clarify it to me...so i guess php is a bit flexible as i can access the array with strings in both cases? anyway i will pay more attention in future
so, can you tell why the first row is not being printed? even after correcting the code as you suggested?

Comment: @l736k : can you check if the query is returning all requested rows ? I'm asking it because the fetch handles the resultset, coming from the querytask. If the row is missing, then it's from the querytask. Also, can you mark this as answer for future users ?

Comment: found the issue: i was executing twice the `mysqli_fetch_array($result_odg)`

Answer (score 0):

To make query fast select only those fields which needed.In this case your query should be like:

```
$result_odg = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT testo FROM agenda WHERE data = '" . $today . "' AND odg IS NOT NULL");
```

Comment: hi, i would have refined the query once tested that the function worked correctly